# How can I pass multiple variables into a component in Angular 2?

Tags: variables, angular, input, components

I am currently using the @Input on my child component, and passing in one variable, but I can't figure out how to pass in a second one.

Comment: ...add another input?

Comment: @jonrsharpe or object

Comment: Oh my god :( , this killed me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, didn't realize you can put two @Input's on the same component. I was trying to squeeze two variables into the same @Input. I thought anything that started with @ could only be used once lol.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, See this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-multiple-variable-input

You can pass all your variable as Object:

**In Parent**

```
/* parent.component.ts file */

export class ParentComponent{

      parentVariables:Object = {
          variable1 : "Temp String",
          variable2 : 23 // Temp Number
      }

}
```

```
<!-- parent.component.html file -->

<app-child [childVariables]="parentVariables"> </app-child>
```

**In Child**

```
/* child.component.ts file */

export class ChildComponent{

    @Input()
    childVariables:any;

}
```

```
<!-- child.component.html file -->

 variable1 : {{childVariables.variable1}} <br />
 variable2 : {{childVariables.variable2 }}
```